# Problem with named constructor with istream as argument

Tags: c++, stream, named-constructor

I'm trying to create a named constructor for my class Matrix, with an input as a stream from which I can read the values for the initialization.

```
#include <istream>
// ...

class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(int);
    // some methods
    static Matrix *newFromStream(istream&);

private:
    int n;
    std::valarray< Cell > data;
};
```

The method should be implemented more or less like this

```
Matrix *Matrix::newFromStream(istream &ist) {

    // read first line and determine how many numbers there are
    string s;
    getline( ist, s );
    ...
    istringstream iss( s, istringstream::in);

    int n = 0, k = 0;
    while ( iss >> k)
        n++;
    Matrix *m = new Matrix( n );    

    // read some more values from ist and initialize        

    return m;
}
```

However, while compiling, I get an error in the declaration of the method (line 74 is where the prototype is defined, and 107 where the implementation starts)

```
hitori.h:74: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘(’ token
hitori.cpp:107: error: no ‘Matrix* Matrix::newFromStream(std::istream&)’ member function declared in class ‘Matrix’
```

These errors, however, I do not get when defining and implementing a named constructor with a simple parameter, like an int.

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you missing `std::`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`istream` is in the namespace `std`:

```
static Matrix *newFromStream(std::istream&);
```

The error indicates it's lost once it gets to `istream`. Change it in both header and source, of course. A couple notes:

In your header, use `<iosfwd>` instead of `<istream>`, and in your source file use `<istream>`. This is more "correct" and may speed up compilation.

Also, do you really want to return newly allocated memory? This is risky and isn't terribly safe. Stack-allocation would be much easier, and maybe even faster.

Lastly, just something to keep in mind: You're very close to having a good `operator<<`. You can implement it in terms of your current function:

```
std::istream& operator<<(std::istream& pStream, Matrix& pResult)
{
    // ... book keeping for istream

    pResult = Matrix::from_stream(pStream);

    // ... more book keeping
}
```

Comment: and similarly use `std::istream` in the implementation.

Comment: @quamrana: Usually assumed I think, but I'll add.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!
And yes, an >>operator should probably be more appropriate.

Regarding the memory, I only know the size of Matrix when I read the first line from the stream.
Do you mean I should do something like

Matrix m();
cin >> m;

and that I have some kind of resize method inside 'from_stream'?

Comment: @mvaz: I mean make the return value `Matrix` instead of `Matrix*`, and change `while ( iss >> k) n++; Matrix *m = new Matrix( n );` to `while ( iss >> k) n++; Matrix m( n );`.